# Modify and open options menu inside a SurfaceView

Tags: android, menu, surfaceview

So im writing my first small game for Android, using a SurfaceView called Panel, which is a seperate class and not a subclass of the GameActivity. When the game ends, I'd like to modify the options menu depending on wether the player won or lost, and then open it.
Any suggestions on how to do that?

GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

private static final int MENU_PAUSE = 1;
private static final int MENU_RESUME = 2;
private static final int MENU_RESTART = 3;
private static final int MENU_QUIT = 4;

private Panel _panel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    _panel = new Panel(this, 01);
    setContentView(_panel);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MENU_PAUSE, 0, "Pause");
    menu.add(0, MENU_RESUME, 0, "Resume");
    menu.add(0, MENU_RESTART, 0, "Restart");
    menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_PAUSE:
            _panel.pause();
            return true;
        case MENU_RESUME:
            _panel.resume();
            return true;
        case MENU_RESTART:
            _panel = new Panel(this, 01);
            setContentView(_panel);
        case MENU_QUIT:
            _panel.stop();
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void openMenu(){
    openOptionsMenu();
}}
```

Panel (shortend):

```
class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener {
// Game Vars
    public Panel(Context context, int level) {
        super(context);
        _holder = getHolder();
        _holder.addCallback(this);
        _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        _handler = new Handler();
        _context = context;
        setFocusable(true);
        start();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

    private void win(){
    }

    private void lose(){

    }


}
```